Disable Unity in VMware Workstation Pro 17?
When doing malware analysis in a VM should I disable Unity? It’s a feature under: VM tab, Settings, Options tab. On the list there Unity is between VNC Connections and Appliance View. Unity has these boxes to check or uncheck:
Unity window decorations
Show borders
Show badges
Use a custom color in window borders
Applications
Enable application menu
But no option to disable Unity altogether it seems. Is it best to disable Unity when doing malware analysis in a VM? And should the VM, when being powered on, be in fullscreen mode to make it safer during malware analysis? Right now the VM is in windowed mode. Does it mean that Unity is enabled?

Don't you have to specifically enable Unity mode?

I’m totally new to VMs, so don’t ask me. I did not enable Unity or even see Unity in the Options list, I think if I remember correctly, when setting up the VM yesterday. Entered the VM again today and noticed Unity on the list. Don’t know if it’s enabled or not.

Are you asking whether you SHOULD disable Unity, or HOW to disable Unity? You may have multiple questions in your post. Please choose one and focus on it.

With the current and only supported version of VMWare Workstation, when a VM is running, there is a button to enable Unity mode. A VM does not by default run in Unity mode.
